# Magento2.3.4 resized images doesn't show in category page, cart page, checkout page and minicart

Tags: php, magento2

I am working in a magento website which has nearly 3000 products. For those products thumbnail, base and small image are different images. Our client wants all the images shown in the category page, product page minicart, cart page and checkout page to be same. I have migrated this website to Magento2.3.4 recently when I migrated I have run the images resize command it took nearly 23 hours to complete. As my client wants all to be same I changed in etc/view.xml of my theme to type "image" where they were thumbnail and small image before. Now I ran the images:resize command it completed successfully but no image was seen in category page or cart page or checkout page or minicart all shows the placeholder image. I have cleared cache and run reindex command. Nothing helped. I have also changed my luma theme's view.xml my theme ones. Can anyone help me to solve this issue

My view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
<media>
    <images module="Magento_Catalog">
        <image id="bundled_product_customization_page" type="thumbnail">
            <width>140</width>
            <height>140</height>
        </image>
        <image id="cart_cross_sell_products" type="thumbnail">
            <width>200</width>
            <height>248</height>
        </image>
        <image id="cart_page_product_thumbnail" type="image">
            <width>165</width>
            <height>165</height>
        </image>
        <image id="category_page_grid" type="image">
            <width>240</width>
            <height>300</height>
        </image>
        <image id="category_page_grid-hover" type="small_image">
            <width>240</width>
            <height>300</height>
        </image>
        <image id="category_page_list" type="image">
            <width>265</width>
            <height>265</height>
        </image>
        <image id="category_page_list-hover" type="small_image">
            <width>240</width>
            <height>300</height>
        </image>
        <image id="customer_account_my_tags_tag_view" type="thumbnail">
            <width>100</width>
            <height>100</height>
        </image>
        <image id="customer_account_product_review_page" type="image">
            <width>285</width>
            <height>285</height>
        </image>
        <image id="customer_shared_wishlist" type="thumbnail">
            <width>113</width>
            <height>113</height>
        </image>
        <image id="gift_messages_checkout_small_image" type="thumbnail">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>75</height>
        </image>
        <image id="gift_messages_checkout_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
            <width>100</width>
            <height>100</height>
        </image>
        <image id="mini_cart_product_thumbnail" type="image">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>75</height>
        </image>
        <image id="new_products_content_widget_grid" type="thumbnail">
            <width>240</width>
            <height>300</height>
        </image>
        <image id="new_products_content_widget_list" type="thumbnail">
            <width>270</width>
            <height>340</height>
        </image>
        <image id="new_products_images_only_widget" type="thumbnail">
            <width>78</width>
            <height>78</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_base_image" type="image">
            <width>265</width>
            <height>265</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_comparison_list" type="thumbnail">
            <width>140</width>
            <height>140</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_page_image_large" type="image"/>
        <image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image">
            <width>1000</width>
            <height>1240</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_page_image_small" type="small_image">
            <width>88</width>
            <height>110</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_page_main_image" type="image">
            <width>1000</width>
            <height>1240</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_page_main_image_default" type="image">
            <width>1000</width>
            <height>1240</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_page_more_views" type="thumbnail">
            <width>88</width>
            <height>110</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_stock_alert_email_product_image" type="small_image">
            <width>76</width>
            <height>76</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_small_image" type="small_image">
            <width>135</width>
            <height>135</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_thumbnail_image" type="thumbnail">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>75</height>
        </image>
        <image id="recently_compared_products_grid_content_widget" type="small_image">
            <width>240</width>
            <height>300</height>
        </image>
        <image id="recently_compared_products_images_names_widget" type="thumbnail">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>90</height>
        </image>
        <image id="recently_compared_products_images_only_widget" type="thumbnail">
            <width>76</width>
            <height>76</height>
        </image>
        <image id="recently_compared_products_list_content_widget" type="small_image">
            <width>270</width>
            <height>340</height>
        </image>
        <image id="recently_viewed_products_grid_content_widget" type="small_image">
            <width>240</width>
            <height>300</height>
        </image>
        <image id="recently_viewed_products_images_names_widget" type="small_image">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>90</height>
        </image>
        <image id="recently_viewed_products_images_only_widget" type="small_image">
            <width>76</width>
            <height>76</height>
        </image>
        <image id="recently_viewed_products_list_content_widget" type="small_image">
            <width>270</width>
            <height>340</height>
        </image>
        <image id="related_products_list" type="small_image">
            <width>152</width>
            <height>190</height>
        </image>
        <image id="review_page_product_image" type="small_image">
            <width>285</width>
            <height>285</height>
        </image>
        <image id="rss_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>75</height>
        </image>
        <image id="sendfriend_small_image" type="small_image">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>75</height>
        </image>
        <image id="shared_wishlist_email" type="small_image">
            <width>135</width>
            <height>135</height>
        </image>
        <image id="side_column_widget_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>90</height>
        </image>
        <image id="upsell_products_list" type="small_image">
            <width>152</width>
            <height>190</height>
        </image>
        <image id="wishlist_sidebar_block" type="thumbnail">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>90</height>
        </image>
        <image id="wishlist_small_image" type="small_image">
            <width>113</width>
            <height>113</height>
        </image>
        <image id="wishlist_thumbnail" type="small_image">
            <width>240</width>
            <height>300</height>
        </image>
    </images>
</media>
<vars module="Magento_Catalog">

    <!-- Gallery and magnifier theme settings. Start -->
    <var name="gallery">
        <var name="nav">thumbs</var> <!-- Gallery navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
        <var name="loop">true</var> <!-- Gallery navigation loop (true/false) -->
        <var name="keyboard">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off keyboard arrows navigation (true/false) -->
        <var name="arrows">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview (true/false) -->
        <var name="caption">false</var> <!-- Display alt text as image title (true/false) -->
        <var name="allowfullscreen">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off fullscreen (true/false) -->
        <var name="navdir">horizontal</var> <!-- Sliding direction of thumbnails (horizontal/vertical) -->
        <var name="navarrows">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off on the thumbs navigation sides (true/false) -->
        <var name="navtype">slides</var> <!-- Sliding type of thumbnails (slides/thumbs) -->
        <var name="transition">
            <var name="effect">slide</var> <!-- Sets transition effect for slides changing (slide/crossfade/dissolve) -->
            <var name="duration">500</var> <!-- Sets transition duration in ms -->
        </var>
        <var name="fullscreen">
            <var name="nav">thumbs</var> <!-- Fullscreen navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
            <var name="loop">true</var> <!-- Fullscreen navigation loop (true/false/null) -->
            <var name="keyboard">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off keyboard arrows navigation (true/false/null) -->
            <var name="arrows">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview (true/false/null) -->
            <var name="caption">false</var> <!-- Display alt text as image title (true/false) -->
            <var name="navdir">horizontal</var> <!--Sliding direction of thumbnails in full screen(horizontal/vertical)  -->
            <var name="thumbwidth">150</var> <!-- Width of thumbnails in fullscreen -->
            <var name="thumbheight">150</var> <!-- Height of thumbnails in fullscreen -->
            <var name="navigation_carousel">true</var> <!-- Display navigation thumbs as carousel (true/false) -->
            <var name="transition">
                <var name="effect">dissolve</var> <!-- Sets transition effect for slides changing (slide/crossfade/dissolve) -->
                <var name="duration">500</var> <!-- Sets transition duration in ms -->
                <var name="carousel">true</var> <!-- Display navigation thumbs as carousel (true/false) -->
            </var>
        </var>
    </var>

    <var name="magnifier">
        <var name="fullscreenzoom">5</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
        <var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
        <var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
        <var name="width"></var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
        <var name="height"></var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
        <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
        <var name="enabled">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
    </var>

    <var name="breakpoints">
        <var name="mobile">
            <var name="conditions">
                <var name="max-width">767px</var>
            </var>
            <var name="options">
                <var name="options">
                    <var name="nav">dots</var>
                </var>
                </var>
        </var>
    </var>
    <!-- end. Gallery and magnifier theme settings -->

    <var name="product_small_image_sidebar_size">100</var>  <!-- Override for small product image -->
    <var name="product_base_image_size">275</var>           <!-- Override for base product image -->
    <var name="product_base_image_icon_size">48</var>       <!-- Base product image icon size -->

    <var name="product_list_image_size">166</var>           <!-- New Product image size used in product list -->
    <var name="product_zoom_image_size">370</var>           <!-- New Product image size used for zooming -->

    <var name="product_image_white_borders">0</var>
</vars>
<vars module="Magento_Bundle">
    <var name="product_summary_image_size">58</var>         <!-- New Product image size used for summary block-->
</vars>
<vars module="Js_Bundle">
    <var name="bundle_size">1MB</var>
</vars>
<exclude>
    <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.details.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.details.min.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.hoverIntent.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.min.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::mage/captcha.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::mage/dropdown_old.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::mage/list.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::mage/loader_old.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::mage/webapi.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::moment.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::requirejs/require.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::date-format-normalizer.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::legacy-build.min.js</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::modernizr</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::tiny_mce</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::varien</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::jquery/editableMultiselect</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::jquery/jstree</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::jquery/fileUploader</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::css</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::lib</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::extjs</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::prototype</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::scriptaculous</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::mage/requirejs</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::mage/adminhtml</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::mage/backend</item>
    <item type="directory">Magento_Swagger::swagger-ui</item>
</exclude>
```